# Processing Unprocessed Records in Kafka on Recovery/Rebalance

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm using Spring Kafka to interface with my Kafka instance. Assume that I have a single topic with, say, 2+ partitions.

In the instances where, for example, my Spring Kafka-based application crashes (or even rebalances), and then comes back online and there are messages waiting in the topic, I'm currently using a strategy where the latest committed offsets for each partition are stored in an external store, which I then look up on a consumer's assignment to a partition and then seek to that offset to resume processing.

(This is based on a strategy I'd read about in an O'Reilly book.)

Is there a better way of handling this situation in order to implement "exactly once" semantics and not to miss any waiting messages? Or is there a better/more idiomatic way with Spring Kafka to handle this situation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using the idempotent producer/consumer transaction settings of Kafka?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you dont checkpoint your offsets to kafka itself?

generally, your options for "exactly once" processing are:

1. store your offsets and your side-effects together transactionally. this is only possible if your side effects go into a transaction-capable system (say a database)
2. use kafka transactions. this is a simplified variant of 1 as long as your side effects go to the same kafka cluster you read from
3. come up with a scheme that allows you to detect and disregard duplicates downstream of your kafka pipeline (aka idempotence)

Comment: The book I read raises a good point (albeit a paranoid one) of a specific use case that's relevant to me:It's possible to process and store the record into a database (which I'm doing), but the application could crash in between that operation and committing the offset in Kafka.

I'm not 100% familiar with using Kafka transactions; perhaps I should look into that.

Re #3: I'm assuming you mean a "read from the beginning of the partition" action on partition assignment...Given the potential number of messages I would have to go through and check against the DB for dupes, that could be slow.

Comment: start a DB transaction. in said transaction store both your output (insert result into some_table?) AND your offsets (insert {topic}, {partition}, {offset} into offsets_table), then commit the transaction - either you stored both result and offset, or neither (or your database isnt ACID compliant)

Comment: I believe that's what I describe in my original question: Storing that info in a separate store (implied transactional; my bad for not being explicit). Is there a better way to do it, though? E.g. #2 from your answer?

Comment: #2 from my answer would be the example code presented here - https://www.confluent.io/blog/transactions-apache-kafka/. more specifically - https://gist.github.com/apurvam/db694549dd149aca1bd6c67ed835f4ea#file-kafkatransactionsexample-java. note that it only works if your outputs all go to the same kafka cluster you consume from

Comment: Ah, right, but since the records/side effects are being stored in a separate store/database by the consumer, then the strategy I defined in my original question sounds like it is perhaps the best option.

Comment: in my experience there comes a step in the processing pipeline where most people want to interact with something beyond kafka (send an email, hit a rest api, etc). this is where #2 tends to break and requires some combination of 1 and 3

Comment: Is #3 necessary if #1 is implemented, though? Can you name a situation where #1 is implemented but #3 is still required?

Comment: #3 is usually used when "producing" (or delivering) into external systems that cannot be made part of a single giant transaction. if everything you deal with supports 2-phase transactions youre lucky.